# How to find a user phone country code form current location using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

Using JS, on a wab browser. NOT native or phone-gap or that sorts,
Any one knows how to find a mobile users "phone country code" by his/hers location? not looking to know the number or any thing like that, just getting the phone country code from the device position.

Native developers has that API, why not web?

googles GeoName API doesn't return this from what i read. and i couldn't find any API for getting the country phone code by geolocation.

It's weird that i couldn't find any question same to this nowhere.

Comment: Try with the HTM5 Geolocation: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: 10x, geolocation returns lots of things, i'm taking the long and lat from there but from what i've read it doesn't return the phone code number (that 3 digits number, in most cases, that comes before the phone number ), i need to get that from some other api and just can't find the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to get clients country name and then  match it to a database containing the country phone.

Here is the database:
https://gist.github.com/adhipg/1600028

And here is the code to get the clients country:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        $.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode', {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
            type: 'JSON'
        }, function(result) {
            alert(result.countryName);
        });
    });
}​
```

If you don't want to use a username for the last piece of code you can you this code:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.city, response.country);
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: 10x. The thing with 'http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode' is that it asks for username and if i write my google api user name every one that knows any thing about JS can get it and use it.... so this API doesn't help me in client side code... or am i wrong?

Comment: @Erez just edited the answer. You will find another option so you don't have to use your username.

Comment: @Erez nevermind. Seems that http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/coordinates2politics/ is down, you can try using a demo as username.

Comment: @Erez just updated again the second piece of code, that should work! You do not need to use geolocation but it gives you what you want. Here is also a more detailed example: http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/

Comment: thank, i'm marking your app as correct but going with server approach to get the country name and using the table of countries to phone country codes to get the code

Comment: Use https://secure.geonames.org/ for https sites. And url is now http://api.geonames.org/ for http sites.